# Script disable in text boxes

Tags: jquery

How can I prevent a script from executing in text boxes, by using jQuery?

Here is my complete  problem:

I want to send a message to  someone using jQuery; if I entered a script tags like `a`, `href`, `script`, etc. they are not appearing in the other's message. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Your question makes little sense in its current form. Please try to explain your problem in more detail, providing code where relevant.

Comment: @jamiec i want to ping some code to my friend ..but the html tags in the text  are not appearing to my friend

Comment: Explain "ping some code" - that could mean a whole bunch of stuff.

Comment: like ...
me :hi james  is it my code correct in home page ??
i'm sending the html code i written 

html
input type=text........
.............
but in the receiving end that code not appearing ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `Encode` the text written by the users.

Most common way is doing it server side, for example using ASP you'll need to:

```
strData = Server.HTMLEncode(strData);
```

And then if the data contains `<b>hello</b>` the users will see it literally.

To do it client side: [HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding)

Answer (score 1):

The question you should be asking is:

> How can I render text containing HTML as text instead of HTML?

As your examples are all about HTML, not script.

Since you are using jQuery, add it to the document using `$element.text(text)` and not `$element.html(text)`.